# Issue with Rest API calls for AppDynamics

Tags: python-3.x, appdynamics

I'm trying to get the list of existing Applications using python script.
Here is my script which fails. I'm new to python scripting. Basically I want to login to the application first and list the existing applications using the python script.

```
import requests
import json
url = "https://account.saas.appdynamics.com"
ploads = { 'Account': 'account',
           'Username': 'sara',
           'Password': 'passwd' }
response = requests.request("GET", url, params=ploads) #this will login to the application.
surl = "https://account.saas.appdynamics.com/controller/restui/v1/app/list/ids" #api call to list the application IDs
sresponse = requests.request("GET", surl)
r = json.loads(sresponse.text)
print(r)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly call for registered applications info from the API if you have the correct credentials. Also note that username is in fact in the format "`<userName>@<accountName>`".

I have tested the below script as working against a test controller:

```
import requests
credentials = {
    "Account": "<accountName>",
    "Username": "<userName>@<accountName>",
    "Password": "<password>"
}
applicationsUrl = "https://" + credentials["Account"] + ".saas.appdynamics.com/controller/rest/applications"
response = requests.get(applicationsUrl, auth=(credentials["Username"], credentials["Password"]))
print(response.text)
```

For this call to work your user needs to have the "Account Owner" permission.